# How is recur being used here? [Clojure]

Tags: clojure

I thought I understood recur, but the following usage doesn't make sense:

```
(fn gcd [a b] 
    (if (= b 0) 
        a 
        (recur b (rem a b))))
```

The function retrieves the greatest common divisor for two numbers. For 4 and 2, the function would give 2.

I know that recur can be bound to functions, but I would think that 'b' is just cycled through the recur without any change. You generally need to put in something like a (inc b) to allow the value in the loop to change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gcd function here uses the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers.

The function works and does terminate because the argument list contains `[a b]` but the recur is called for `b, (rem a b)`. Note that the place of `b` is changed here (from seond place to first place).

The value of `a` is changed because the value of `b` is assigned to it. Also, the value of `b` is changed because `(rem a b)` is assigned to it (thus decreasing). Therefore both values decrease when the calls are repeated and eventually one of them reaches 0 (that stops the recursion).

Answer (score 2):

```
(fn gcd [a b] 
  (if (= b 0) a 
    (recur b (rem a b))))
```

For example I call this function with argument a = 24, b = 16.
This function is called recursively as long as b isn't zero.

```
(gcd 24 16) 
=> (gcd 16 8)) #_"because b=24 doesn't equal to zero and 8 is the reminder of 24/16" 
=> (gcd 8 0) #_"0 is the reminder of 16/8"
=> 8
```

This calculation stops because b reaches zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you want to change the values in a recursive call so eventually your test will succeed, and you'll break out of the recursion. This algorithm does exactly that by sending the new first-parameter with the value of the old second-parameter, and the new second-parameter is recomputed based upon the old first and old second-parameters.

Try adding something like `(println "a:" a "b:" b)` before the if statement in the function, and you'll see the values cycling through as it seeks the answer.